# Getting checkbox value and display a div using jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I would like to display a div which is by default is hidden, if checkbox value is "Yes". here is my html code

```
 <div class="bestsell_wrapper">
    <div style="display:none;" itemprop="best-sell" class="best-sell"></div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="bestsell_chkbox" name="bestsellchk_box"
        value="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_overlay1')%>" style="display:none;" />  
</div>
```

There are multiple items and for which the checkbox value is "Yes" i want to display div having class name "best-sell".This jquery code i have tried but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".bestsell_chkbox").each(function(){
        if ($("this").val().trim() == "Yes")
        {
            $(".best-sell").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this behaviour when the checkbox is clicked, or on load of the page?

Comment: There are unbalanced parentheses and curly braces there, this won't run at all. Also, you're iterating through all of the checkboxes of class `.bestsell_chkbox` and running that code, not on click or checked change. Also, `$("this")` will try and select all elements of type `this`. Remove the `"`: `$(this)`

Comment: i gets the value using value="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_overlay1')%>" if it is Yes i need to show div

Comment: @user2787474 - dear you need to format your question and provide more information. (like is it repetitive `div` and `Checkbox` , is it inside the table with multiple rows  ETC... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your jQuery to:

```
$(".bestsell_chkbox").each(function(){
    var $that = $(this);
    if ($that.val().trim() == "Yes") {
        $that.prev(".best-sell").css("display", "block"); 
    }
})
```

Comment: its showing this div for every items condition is not working

Comment: fine its working now added $(this).prev(".best-sell").css("display", "block");

Comment: Cool. Made one more edit to answer to snap the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do the following

```
if($(this).val().trim() == "Yes"){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $("input.bestsell_chkbox[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("checked") !== "checked") {// do your stuff here}
});
```

Comment: value is set manually so i need to check only value "Yes" using checkbox class name

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="bestsell_chkbox" name="bestsellchk_box"
 checked="<%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_overlay1').Equals("Yes")? "checked" : String.Empty%>" style="display:none;" /> why this well you are using input type checkbox not hidden or text http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a few mistakes in your Script. If you want this to show only checkboxes on load this is the code that will get it done.

```
$(".bestsell_chkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val().trim() == "Yes"){
        $(".bestsell_chkbox").css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

Your code was trying to **show** div but your div is already visible. Your checkbox was hidden. That is why I changed the class inside **if** clause

Comment: its hidden  <div style="display:none;" itemprop="best-sell" class="best-sell">

Comment: Oh right. Just change the class to div's class and remove hidden style fro checkbox. Or add a code that will change the checkbox and div to **display:block**

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bestsell_chkbox").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr("checked"))
    {
        $(this).closest('.best-sell').css({'display':'block'});
    }
   });
});
</script>
```